# Feature Extraction with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, feature-extraction

I am wondering whether there is any open source or free library for Image feature extraction with Javascript? I am developing an app where I need to use an algorithm like SIFT. It is tough to implement in JS, and I couldn't find a good SIFT implementation in JS. I thought of implementing a feature extraction library in JS if one doesn't exist. Please can anybody help me to find a good solution or guide me to write one from scratch.

Thanks,
Keshan.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with implementation for sift descriptor in JS, yet, it might worth starting with a simple HOG descriptor which has a great javascript implementation in https://github.com/harthur/hog-descriptor.

You should also check jsfeat, a javascript computer vision library  http://inspirit.github.com/jsfeat/

Answer (score 4):

[Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/edges/) has an edge detection function and works in browser JavaScript, that could be a good start.